# PassportJS always showing "User Already Registered"

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, passport.js, stripe-payments

I am using passport JS to register Users on my website. Inside of the registration request I am attempting to also using Stripe to charge my users money. I am also use Ajax because this is a single page application.

It seems to get through the code just fine but I'm afraid the Ajax might be causing problems. One odd thing is the response is not always the same. Sometimes the Stripe charge goes through and sometimes it does not.

Here the issue: When I register as a new user with a username I am 100% sure is NOT taken - it will say "UserExistsError: A user with the given username is already registered"

How would I change my code to fix this?

```
app.post("/quiz", function(req, res){

    var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
console.log(' CHARGE STEP 1')
// Charge the user's card:
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 2800,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
  // asynchronously called
});

    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user){
        console.log(' CHARGE STEP 2')
      if(err) { } 
      if(user) { 
          //this is how you sent the "USER NAME TAKEN ERROR"
          res.json({"message": "false" });
      }
    });
   }); 


      //continue with your registration logic once it has been checked that the username is not taken!!!
      var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username, datapoint: req.body.datapoint});
      User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){

            if(err){
            console.log("this error" + err)


          } else {
          passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
            //  req.flash("success", "Welcome to JobQuiz " + user.username);
            //  res.redirect("jobquiz");
             res.json({"message": "true" });
            //  res.redirect('/jobquiz')
             console.log(' CHARGE STEP 3')

          });

          }

      });
});
```

AJAX CODE HERE

```
$(function() {
                $("#checkpaymentForm").on("submit", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType:'json',

                 success: function (data) {
                     console.log(data)
                    if (data.message === "false") {
                        $('#testERROR').html('Whoops, that username is taken')
                    }
                      else if (data.message === "true") {
                        $('#testERROR').html('Thank you for joining!')

                      }

                 }

                    });
                });

                });
```

Comment: Have you tried logging what data goes out from ajax?

Comment: @Kunkka I've tried console.log(data) which gives me a true or false as expected.

Comment: Ah no , i meant log the request which goes out from ajax. there could perhaps be something wrong with the data which ajax serializes

Comment: @Kunkka hmmm how would I log that? :)